# Redirecting a url containing a hollow square character

Tags: apache, url, redirect, special-characters

A link from a website beyond my control links to an erroneous url. The erroneous url contains a hollow square character. **How do I write a redirect 301 to deal with this occurance?** When attempting to paste the character in the .htaccess file I get a question mark.

If I need more than a redirect 301, then what?

Comment: Can you use a hex viewer to look at the bytes?

Comment: "Hollow square character" sounds like a Unicode character out of place. Looking at the bytes to find out what was meant would indeed be the best idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** I used **â€‹** in it's place and it worked. I got this by switching from chrome and opening the link in firefox. The **â€‹** showed up in the 404 error description area.

Comment: While this solution will take care of this specific character, it probably won't cover all instances of a bad character, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

The hollow square character isn't an actual character, but a set of unprintable bytes.  It could be a virtually limitless set of values.  What you should do instead is set up rule to say "If the character is not in this defined set, it is invalid"

```
RedirectMatch 301 !^([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/])*$ http://myserver.com/desired/redirect/url
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work. If not let me know and I'll help revise it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21617317/411615 I hope you check my question.. thank you.